# spring queryForInt method throws exception invalid column type

Tags: spring, spring-jdbc

I am using queryForInt() method of spring JDBC template. It has two arguments: query string and second arguments for parametrized SQL. I have sql query like: select count(*) from table X where x.x1=? and x.x2=? . I am passing two integer values in arguments list:

- args.add(12); args.add(50);

  Data type of x1 and x2 in DB is Number.

  This method is always throwing PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [<>>]; SQL state [99999]; error code [17004]; Invalid column type

I am not able to figure what is wrong.
However if I hard-code the parameter value in SQL and use same in single parameter version method of queryForInt; it works: "select count(*) from table X where x.x1=12 and x.x2=50". This works.

Any idea what is issue here? I am using spring 3.0.6 version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i understand you r code looks like:

```
List args = new ArrayList();
args.add(12); args.add(50);
jdbcTemplate.queryForInt(sql, args);
```

but `queryForInt` expect array of objects here (`Object...`) not a list, and interprets args as single argument. To fix it code should be looks like:

```
List args = new ArrayList();
args.add(12); args.add(50);
jdbcTemplate.queryForInt(sql, args.toArray());
```